# Ansible regex_replace

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to capture the main version number of a variable, and to do this I'm trying to remove the numbers after the main version number:

In `variable.yml`:

```
version: 3.9.5
main_version: "{{ version | regex_replace('^.*(..)$', '')}}"
```

This should give me `3.9`, however debug gives me nothing.

What's the correct way of doing this?

(And making sure that it would still be able to handle things such as `3.10.1`, so that would return a `main_version` of `3.10`, and also things such as `3.10.1-rcblah`, and that would return a `main_version` of `3.10`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your regexp should be something like:

```
'^.*(\.[0-9]*)$'
```

But why don't you use `version_compare`? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison

Comment: Thanks, I had to double escape for yml to accept it. So my full command is `main_version: "{{ version | regex_replace('^(.*)(\\.[0-9]*)$', '\\1') }}"`.

Comment: I had a look at version_compare, but couldn't see how that would work for my scenario?